# Turning off ggplot2 grids in rpy2

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

What's the right way to turn off all grids in Rpy2 while using the `theme_bw` theme? I know I can turn on `theme_bw` as follows:

`ggplot2.theme_set(ggplot2.theme_bw(12))`

but unsure how to turn off the grids. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically done the same way one would do it when using ggplot2 from R.

Here is an example that turn off the grid intersecting with the X axis. More ways to "theme" a plot can be found in documentations and tutorials for ggplot2.

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 import ggplot, \
                               aes_string, \
                               geom_histogram, \
                               element_blank, \
                               theme_bw, \
                               theme
from rpy2.robjects import r

nogrid_x_theme = theme(**{'panel.grid.major.x': element_blank(),
                         'panel.grid.minor.x': element_blank()})
iris = r('iris')
p = ggplot(iris) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x = 'Sepal.Width'))
p += theme_bw() + nogrid_x_theme
p.plot()
```

Comment: thank you. last question: how can I apply this globally to all plots made with ggplot2 using rpy2, rather than adding it to each plot object with `p += ... nogrid_x_theme` as you have it?

Comment: @user248237 : May be write a Python function that make the full plot from a data frame so you do not see the addition ?